# Différence entre « proof of concept » et « prototype »

Tags: expressions, comparaison-de-langues, emprunts

J'entends de plus en plus l'emprunt "POC" dans mon travail (je suis développeuse d'applications). De ce que j'en vois, il s'agit de réaliser une partie particulière d'une solution pour la valider avant de la mettre en place (d'où le terme "Proof of Concept" : on veut faire faire ses preuves à l'idée). Toutefois, j'ai du mal à voir la différence avec le terme "prototype", qui est lui bien français. Les articles que j'ai pu trouver sur le Web ne concernent que la différence entre le "prototype" en anglais et le terme POC, mais je n'ai rien trouvé sur le mot français. A mes yeux, il s'agirait plutôt d'un terme à la mode (l'anglais a le vent en poupe dans notre vocabulaire, en particulier dans l'industrie), mais je n'en suis pas certaine.
Savez-vous s'il existe une vraie différence entre l'emprunt "POC" et le terme français "prototype" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selon moi, un *prototype* est plus avancé en termes de réalisation qu'un *proof of concept*. Si j'avais à trouver une expression analogue en français, je dirais plutôt *étude de faisabilité*. Si j'avais à parler des deux sans distinguer l'état d'avancement, je parlerais de *maquette*.

Comment: pour moi maquette se rapproche plus d'un prototype, ils sont tous deux fortement axés UX/Usability, le POC étant plutôt technique. A priori on a d'abord la maquette (= wireframes), puis le prototype. Et en fonction du projet on a un POC ou pas...

Answer (score 3):

Suivant les projets et les personnes, il y a forcément recouvrement mais il me semble qu'un prototype correspond à une étape plus avancée que le *proof of concept*.

Un POC (on dit parfois *démonstrateur* en français) permet de valider (ou non) un ou plusieurs choix techniques alors qu'un prototype est un produit fonctionnel proche du produit final envisagé, et permet de valider une architecture complète.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. "Démonstrateur" n'est-il pas plus vieilli que le terme "étude de faisabilité" proposé par @mouviciel ? Je me permets de poser la question, mais les deux termes me plaisent. :)

Comment: Vieilli c'est possible, mais surtout plus utilisé pour de projets matériels plutôt que logiciels. Il est aussi peut-être plus courant en aéronautique qu'ailleurs. Étude de faisabilité est très bien.

Comment: Ah, c'est vrai que le type de projet est aussi important. Voilà qui clarifie les choses. Merci pour votre réponse !

Answer (score 1):

Au [*Grand dictionnaire terminologique*](http://granddictionnaire.com/Gdt_en_bref.aspx) (de l'Office québécois de la langue française) ils ont choisi en 2007 [*démonstration de faisabilité*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8350279) qu'on définit comme la « vérification mise en œuvre pour contrôler la conformité d'un produit ou d'un logiciel avec des spécificités données » (GDT), différemment du [*prototype*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2075799), le « modèle ou mise en œuvre préliminaire permettant l'évaluation de la conception d'un système, de sa réalisation et de son potentiel d'exploitation, ou encore une meilleure identification et compréhension des besoins » (GDT) où on note que ce « système non opérationnel dont toutes les fonctionnalités prévues ont été réalisées est capable de traiter un certain nombre de cas concrets à l'aide de développeurs mais n'a pas encore la solidité industrielle requise pour être mis sur le terrain des usagers » (GDT). Les autres réponses traitent des nuances plus simplement et mieux qu'au lexique.

Comment: C’est quoi le GDT ?

Comment: Le Grand Dictionnaire Terminologique mentionné plus haut dans la réponse, je pense.